# Lumen in a subfolder trailing slashes issue

Tags: nginx, lumen

In `public/index.php` I have changed `$app->run()` to `$app->run($app['request'])` and this resulted in Lumen working in a sub-folder, so this works:

```
http://local.dev/app/
http://local.dev/app/test
```

However if there's a slash at the end of a route then I get a `NotFoundHttpException`. For example:

```
http://local.dev/app/test/
```

I'm using NGINX and my rewrite rule for the folder is:

```
location /app/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /app/index.php?$query_string;
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: How about if you remove the trailing slash from nginx configuration. Read [this article](https://www.scalescale.com/tips/nginx/nginx-remove-trailing-slash/) for more information about how to do that?

Comment: According to the Lumen `.htaccess`, the same as Laravel, trailing slashes are meant to be stripped. Not an nginx user here, but you should be able to do the same there.

Answer (score 0):

If laravel is in a sub-directory use this :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$/ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

instead of this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```